# Finding the highest score

Tags: java

I wrote a program  that prompts the user to enter student's name and score. and finally display the student with highest score.

Here's my code and what should I do.

```
public class Student {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        final int numberOfStudent = 10;
        int count = 0;
        int highestScore = 0;
        String highestScorer = "";
        String x= "";
        int y;
        while (count < numberOfStudent) {
            System.out.println("Enter student's name and score.");
            x = input.next();
            y = input.nextInt();
            count++;
            if (highestScore < y){
                highestScore = y;
                highestScorer = x;
            }

        }
        System.out.println(highestScore +" "+ highestScorer);
    }

}
```

Comment: *what should I do*: Try compiling it and running it, to see if it works fine?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Well, where is the issue after all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, in the end, your `x` contains the last student, not the student with the highest score.

Just as you keep a `highestScore` variable, you should keep a `highestScoreUser` variable. Whenever you update `highestScore`, you should update `highestScoreUser` too.

```
        if (highestScore < y){
            highestScore = y;
            highestScoreUser = x;
        }
```

Comment: What if more than 1 students have same high score?

Answer (score 1):

you can also use `Math.max (highestScore, y)` to keep the max value you need instead of using `if`